# gwt - viewing data of large xml file

Tags: java, gwt

I need to load data from a huge xml file (more than 1 GB) and show it in the browser.
Is there a widget or something else that does this thing without getting stuck?
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Too large. Your browser cannot bear such enormous amount of data. You need some kind of pagination. Which type of data are they? Tabular data?

Comment: The data is a large tree. Is there a way to show only parts of the data (like main nodes) and then show more data on demand? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to paginate your data. Since it is in tree form, use something like a [CellTree](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but I got a little confused with the binding. Is there a way to bind the xml data directly to the tree?